# Rotate Background randomly 90°, 180° and 270°

Tags: jquery, css

I place randomly some div-container on the screen.

```
$(".container").each( function(index) {
    var rNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 5;
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
    $(this).css( {   
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'deg)',
        'top': y,
        'left': x
    } ).delay(200 * index).fadeIn(200);  
} );
```

Now I would like to rotate the background-image of this container (not the content) also randomly for 0°, 90°, 180° or 270°. How can I implement this in the code?

Comment: Rotate it randomly with the same transform as the content, or a different random from the content?

Comment: just rotating the background-image of the .container. The content of the container should stay as it is.

Comment: I believe [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/) tutorial should have what you need

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle.